# Is there a limit to the amount of armor you can have?

Tags: hearthstone

I am currently playing the Warrior character in Hearthstone.
The Warrior class, has the hero ability to gain +2 armor, paying 2 mana crystals.

Besides that, the Warrior has a class cards to add further armor, +5 using Shieldblock.

But lets say that I have a given amount of armor, lets say a 10+ armor and any given health. I have the Shieldblock card on my hand, but I wouldn't waste it if there is a limit to the amount of armor I have.

**Are there any limit to how much armor a hero can have in Hearthstone?**

Comment: I will only post this as a comment because I cannot find if there is a for sure upper bound. That being said I have seen armor values get very high (16+). So I do not think there is a feasible limit. I can test with friends later.

Comment: Assuming that fatigue sets in around turn ~26 and reduces your armor, I imagine there is a soft cap around ~60. (2 per turn (starting on turn 2) + 5 per shield block (2 total)) Not counting use of Lorewalker Cho and barring any actual cap.

Comment: I was able to get it up to 34, But ran out of cards^^

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no practical limit to the amount of [armor](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Attribute#Armor) you may possess, because while armor can increase without bound on Warriors (and to a lesser extent, Druids), the game will never last long enough to get anywhere close to any programmatic limit (due to Fatigue, which cumulatively increases each time it hits you).

According to [the wiki](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Fatigue), even if you survive 49 turns over fatigue (by which time you would have been out of cards for at least ~22 turns), the game ends in a draw on the 50th turn.

So Armor Up, and sleep soundly knowing that more armor is never wasted!

Answer (score 6):

With 6 Armorsmiths, a Pyromancer on one side, 5 Armorsmith, a Pyromancer and a Lorewalker Cho on the other, each side can play 10 Circles of Healing a turnto gain 42 and 36 armor each. Each round includes both players' turns so one would gain 84 armor and the other 72.

At 50 rounds max, the minimum fatigue is 23? I estimate about 1000 armor to be the maximum achievable.

Answer (score -1):

If you use Earthen Scales, Scaled Nightmare and lorewalker cho you can get hundreds of millions of armor. I got 540,542,647 before the game stopped us.

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/122795967933186053/434892920907104266/unknown.png this is a pic of that game

Answer (score -5):

It seems like it stops at 222 for some odd reason.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The reason the armor stops increasing at 222 in this video is not because of a limit on the armor, but rather a limit on the number of bounces that bouncing blade can make.

Comment: I've seen over 250 in a game against a warrior with Justicar Trueheart and Coldarra Drake.