# Is there an effective counter to a hero's armor?

Tags: hearthstone

A warrior I was playing tonight was able to get their armor much higher than I would have liked. In Hearthstone a hero's [armor is similar to a hero's health](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/152262/559) and since there is [no practical limit to the amount of armor a hero can stack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/145560/559), his armor advantage became insurmountable.

While I was being summarily beaten I found myself wondering if there was a card that had any affect on a hero's armor. Essentially something like the [Acidic Swamp Ooze](http://www.hearthhead.com/card=906/acidic-swamp-ooze), but with an effect on armor instead of a hero's weapon. Is there an armor countering card in Hearthstone? If no such card exists what is an effective strategy to control a run away armor train?

Comment: Good question, afaik there is no card which hard counters armor, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: The high armor is just a consequence of you losing the game elsewhere. If you had board control, you should have been able to inflict much more damage than the 2 armor per round your opponent can add.

Comment: at the same time having many .low cost creatures with possible buffs like orcs you could use garrosh's armor buff like a madman i guess

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No** there is no way to counter armor with cards at the moment.

To counter-play against an armor stacking opponent:
 - Be aggressive
 - Do not stall the game

Here is a quote:

> Armor is a form of secondary Health available only to heroes, gained through certain spells, hero powers and minions. Damage taken will always be deducted from Armor before Health. Only when a character has zero Armor will they lose Health from a damaging attack. Armor can effectively extend a hero's Health far beyond the 30 points otherwise allowed.

The following is for informational purposes only, as it only applies to Hearthstone prior to the patch on 11 March 2014 which bug fixed how armor and minions work.

Here are some extra useful niche information:

> While Armor serves as a substitute for Health, for game purposes losing Armor does not count as suffering damage. For example, losing Armor (but not Health) to a Water Elemental's attack will not cause the hero to become Frozen, and loss of Armor will not reduce the summoning cost of Molten Giant.

Source: http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Armor#Armor

The following is for informational purposes only, as it only applies to Hearthstone prior to the patch on 10 Dec 2013 which bugfixed Alexstrasza.

The "15 health"  used to refer to the "current health + armor" total.
Scenario 1: Target Warrior has 28 health and 13 armor. When Alexstrasza targets this Warrior, Alexstrasza visibly deals 26 damage (you see the -26 number) to the target Warrior to result in 15 health and 0 armor left.
Scenario 2: Target Druid has 9 health and 3 armor. When used on the Druid, he will visibly be healed 3 health to result in 12 health and 3 armor.

Comment: Just because there is no specific counter-card (like a spell/battlecry) which can get rid of armor, that doesn't mean there is no actualy counter-play to armor!

Comment: Op asked if there is a counter "card" for armor not counter-play. Counter-play is a nobrainer, don't let him stack armor, be aggressive, the more you stall the stronger he gets.

Comment: Not saying your answer is wrong, but since he also asked about counterplay, you could add that to your answer^^.

Comment: I do not think that the water elemental attack applies anymore, the warrior would get frozen even if you only damage his armor. Edit: yep just found out it changed Patch 1.0.0.4944 (2014-03-11): Water Elemental now freezes armored heroes as intended, updated the answer